# Converting address to geocode, just returns "undefined", why?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocode, google-geocoder

This is what i have:

http://jsfiddle.net/JhCKW/1/

Im using Google maps v3, Geocode.

I made a function showAddress( param ). This takes the param, check if its a address if it is then it returns cords and if its not it returns 0.

If you check the link, you can see I have written the code for this, but I just get a alert "undefined".

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, I've finally realised the case. Problem is not in Google Maps.
You are returning result not from `showAddress` but from callback. So, it's actually goes nowhere. You need to display your result using callback also. Just like this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var geocoder;
  function showAddress(address, callback)
  {
    if (typeof(geocoder) == 'undefined') geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        callback(results[0].geometry.location);
      } else {
        callback(0);
      }
    });
  }

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#address').blur(function(){
      showAddress( $('#address').val(), function(result)
      {
        if (result === 0)
          alert('Adressen not found');
        else{
          alert(result);
          $('#cords').val( result );
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>

<input type="text" name="address" id="address">
```

You can check it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/BgDQc/2/